# Mac os x terminal mail: send multiple outputs in one mail

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a backupscript that executes every 2 weeks with cron on my mac os high sierra.
And that part works and now I want to mail the log to myself using these 2 lines:

> df -Ph /Volumes/USB_Storage >> "/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs/rsync"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.log
>
> cat "/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs/rsync"`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.log | /usr/bin/mail -s "Backuplog" user@gmail.com

the thing is: my backup starts at 10:00 pm september 15 so the logfile is created on the 15th
The backup was ready at 1:00 am september 16 so a new logfile is created.
At the end the mail was send using the logfile that contains the df command from the 16th.

does anyone now how to fix this?
can I create a variable at the begin of the proces that stores the current date and use that?
or can I send a mail that sends the logfile and the df results?

Regards,

Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the date you want to use (and do the same with the complete filename).

```
backupdate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
backupfile="/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs/rsync${backupdate}.log"

df -Ph /Volumes/USB_Storage >> "${backupfile}"
cat "${backupfile}" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Backuplog of ${backupdate}" user@gmail.com
```

Comment: That works like a charm, nice clean code, @Walter A there is a minor error in your code at line 2 at the end: {backupdate).log"  the closing bracket should be curly bracket ;-)

Comment: Bracket fixed. You can also use more vars, like `logdir="/Users/ralphschipper/Documents/Logs"; backupfile="${logdir}/rsync${backupdate}.log" `

Comment: Yes I did something like that, this is my script now: https://pastebin.com/A1k6bhcT
I have add a running option to so I can test some settings in a test enviroment